# How to intercept Enter key in AutoSuggestBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

'Enter' key in AutoSuggestBox calls to QuerySubmitted event, like clicking the icon. It is a Windows 10 project.

I need to discriminate the Enter key because I use it to go to the next field. I tried KeyDown event, but it is not called.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 11):

Don't ask me why, but you need to use `KeyUp` event and everything works fine.
Ex:

```
private void ContactsBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        //some stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this... So weird why KeyDown does not work